# TypeORM: get relations with condition?

Tags: typescript, orm, typeorm

I have 2 `Entity` with relation: `products`, `catogories`

`products`:

```
@ManyToOne(() => Category, category => category.id)
category: Category
```

`catogories`:

```
@OneToMany(() => Product, product =>  product.id)
products: Product[]
```

When I want to get a category with product:

```
categoryRepository.findOne({
  where: {
    id,
  },
  relations: {
    products: true
  }
})
```

It work, but it get all `products` of `category`.

I want to get `products` with `condition` like `limit`, `offset`,...

How can I do that?